# Laravel sqlite database locked

Tags: laravel, sqlite, azure-web-app-service

I am using the Azure web app with PHP 7.3 stack. In my project, we have the feature to sync from mobile to web and for that, we are using the SQLite file. And for other modules, we have a MySQL database.

The mobile app sends the SQLite file and we stored it in the directory. But we try to make a query to the SQLite with PDO then it throws the error that the **database is locked**.

I tried many solutions from the other's answer but not get success.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with permissions of the underlying storage mount.

One option you could try is mounting an Azure File share and persisting the database there, see https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/320889/view.html. The best option however is to utilize a cloud database such as Postgres or MySQL for Azure.